# Conditional expectation of conditional sum(Not fully complete)

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have a question: Determine the conditional expectation $\mathrm{E}(A|B)$ for:

> The number $B(\geq 0)$ of bats that leave a cave at the time of a nuclear explosion has a geometric distribution with mean $\lambda$. Suppose the bats each contribute independent exponentially distributed amounts of wind movement with mean $\frac{1}{\mu}$. Let $A$ be the total amount of wind movement at the time of a nuclear explosion(with no wind movement accumulated if no bats are flying.)

From the accepted answer: I take number $B$ of faults and multiply it with $\frac{1}{\mu}$ to yield $\mathrm{E}(A|B)$ this is because ~ $exp(\frac{1}{\mu})$ applied B times goes to $\frac{B}{\mu}$ due to large numbers right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as a random or conditional sum, and it's quite straight-forward once you wrap your head around the question. The total amount of movement is $A=\sum_{i=1}^b a_i$ where $a_i \sim \text{Exp}(1/\mu)$ and $b$ is the realization of $B$ you condition upon. You want the conditional expectation, so you are using $b$, a fixed constant and not random, and no expectation of $B$ is needed. Since it is a fixed constant, you get that
$$
E(A|B=b)=E\left(\sum_{i=1}^ba_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^bE(a_i)=\sum_{i=1}^b\frac{1}{\mu}=\frac{b}{\mu}.
$$
Note that this is a number. The conditional expectation $E(A|B)$ is a random variable, and is:
$$
E(A|B)=E\left(\sum_{i=1}^Ba_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^BE(a_i)=\sum_{i=1}^B\frac{1}{\mu}=\frac{B}{\mu}.
$$

Comment: So I am summing the number of bats that leave the cave, and letting there number be a constant. Then taking that constant B, and multiplying $a_i$ by it to yield $\frac{b}{\mu}$ which is the expected A given B, which is obviously true since it is based directly off of B.

Comment: Yes, because you are conditioning on a realization of the random variable $B$ (I updated my notation slightly to distinguish between the r.v. $B$ and its realization $b$). I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Yes that is clearer, thank you, a related query: If I wanted to find just $E(A)$ now, it would be $\frac{1}{\mu}$ times expected B. So just $\frac{\lambda}{\mu}$?

Comment: Yes, since $E(E(A|B))=E(A)$ by the law of iterated expectations.

Comment: I looked that rule up, and it goes on about smoothing on$\sigma$-algebras, I don't know anything of these, am I to just assume that this meets those criteria? Just wondering for when I deal with other similar problems. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: I think I am confused by your Riemann sum $\sum_{i=1}^B \frac{1}{\mu}$ and where does $Exp(\frac{1}{\mu}$ go, is it gone because we are taking a sum of it, so it just takes its mean(large numbers or similar logic)?

Comment: See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation. For the sum, $1/\mu$ doesn't depend on the summation index. Summing constants simply means multiplication by the length of the sum, such as $\sum_{i=1}^n 1=n$. So here we have $\sum_{i=1}^B1/\mu=1/\mu\sum_{i=1}^B=1/\mu * B$.

Comment: Yeah that is what I assumed, thanks for that, it was just weird notation on first viewing.